# React-leaflet. Filling a Polygon with a pattern

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

Is there any good solutions for this task?

I tried Leaflet.Pattern library, but it's doesnt draw anything in React app.

code is too large to copy it here, but just some excerpts.

importing StripePattern, define it, then use in Polygon like that:

```
import {StripePattern} from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.pattern'

***
//inside the component or outside, doesn't matter. Had the same effect.
const stripePattern = new StripePattern()

***

//inside the return of component
<Polygon
    fillPattern={stripePattern}
    positions={points}
    interactive={false}
    color={LayerColor.Red}
    weight={0}
    fillOpacity={1.0}
/>
```

There is no troubles in code itself, because all other polygons are drawing fine.